# Intermediate step in bound for Kullback-Leibler (KL) divergence

Tags: probability, information-theory, upper-lower-bounds

### Question

I am having a hard time deriving the first step in the proof of Theorem 3.1 as found in McAllester and Stratos's paper entitled ``Formal Limitations on the Measurement of Mutual Information
'' (Proceedings of the Twenty Third International Conference on Artificial Intelligence and Statistics , 2020), the full text of which is available at the following link
http://proceedings.mlr.press/v108/mcallester20a.html.

Said theorem reads as follows:

> **Theorem 3.1**. Let $B$ be any distribution-free high-confidence lower bound on $D_\text{KL}(p_X||q_X)$ computed with complete knowledge of $p_X$ but only samples from $q_X$.

> More specifically, let $B(p_X, S, \delta)$ be any real-valued function of a distribution $p_X$, a multiset $S$, and a confidence parameter $\delta$ such that, for any $p_X$, $q_X$ and $\delta$, with probability at least 1-$\delta$ over a draw of $S$ from $q_X^N$ we have
> \begin{align*}
>   D_\text{KL}(p_X||q_X) \ge B(p_X, S, \delta)
> \end{align*}
> for any such bound, and for $N\ge2$, for any $q_X$, with probability at least $1-4\delta$ over the draw of $S$ from $q_X^N$ we have
> \begin{align*}
>   B(p_X, S, \delta) \le \text{ln}N.
> \end{align*}

Note in particular, that $p_X$ and $q_X$ are distributions over a random variable $X$ and that $N$ denotes the number of samples drawn from $q_X$.

The proof follows directly in the manuscript:

> *Proof*. Consider distributions $p_X$ and $q_X$ and $N\ge 2$. Define $\tilde{q}_X$ by
> \begin{align*}
> \tilde{q}(x) &= \left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)q_X(x) + \frac{1}{N}p_X(x)
> \end{align*}
> We now have $D_\text{KL}(p_X||\tilde{q}_X)\le \ln N$.
> [...]

How is this first step, i.e. $D_\text{KL}(p_X||\tilde{q}_X)\le \ln N$, derived?

### My attempt so far

\begin{align*}
D_\text{KL}\left(p_X||\tilde{q}_X\right) 
&= \text{E}_{x\sim p_X}\left[-\ln \frac{\tilde{q}_X(x)}{p_X(x)}\right]\\
&= \text{E}_{x\sim p_X}\left[-\ln \tilde{q}_X(x)\right] - \underbrace{\text{E}_{x \sim p_X}\left[-\ln p_X(x)\right]}_{\ge 0,\ \text{entropy term}} \\
&\le \text{E}_{x \sim p_X}\left[-\ln \left(\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)q_X(x) + \frac{1}{N}p_X(x)\right)\right] \\
&\le \text{E}_{x \sim p_X}\left[- \left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right) \ln q_X(x) + -\frac{1}{N}\ln p_X(x) \right] \\
&= \left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right) \text{E}_{x \sim p_X}\left[-\ln q_X(x)\right] + \frac{1}{N}\text{E}_{x \sim p_X}\left[-\ln p_X(x) \right]
\end{align*}
where the second to last step exploites the fact that $-\ln$ is a convex function, and $\tilde{q}$ is a convex combination of $q$ and $p$. However this does not seem to be of any help...

Comment: The approach you're taking is ineffective due to handling the entropy term separately. Instead, observe that for any $x$ with $p(x) > 0,$ $$ \frac{p(x)}{\tilde{q}(x)} \le \frac{p(x)}{p(x)/N} = N,$$ which holds since $(1-1/N)q(x) \ge 0$. But then $\sum p(x) \log \frac{p(x)}{\tilde{q}(x)} \le \sum p(x) \log N = \log N.$

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thank you for providing the solution :)